# Chrome extension to check table and add css from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to make one chrome extension that check the GRADE of the following table and if its over 5 it should put a line over course name like "physics" or "mathematics" etc.

i have this table over here

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="10" class="groupHeader">Semester A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height="25" class="italicHeader">
                    <td valign="top"></td>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top">Course</td>
                    <td valign="top">Type</td>
                    <td valign="top">SM</td>
                    <td valign="top">Hours</td>
                    <td valign="top">ECTS</td>
                    <td valign="top">Grade</td>
                    <td valign="top">Exam</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height="25" bgcolor="#fafafa">
                    <td valign="top">&nbsp;<img align="absbottom" src="images/course4.gif" width="16"></td>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="topBorderLight">(Ν2-1011)&nbsp; PHYSICS<span class="redfonts"></span></td>
                    <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight">COMPULSORY</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight"> 6</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight">6</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight"> 7</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight"><span class="redFonts">5,5</span></td>
                    <td nowrap="true" class="topBorderLight"><span class="tablecell"><i>Α WINTER&nbsp;
                        2012-2013</i></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>



            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I dont know the jquery code to put a line on it but im trying with this code
that makes the color red

```
$("#topBorderLight").css("color","red");
```

But its not working. Anyone can guide me through making it red OR putting a line through it if the grade is over 5?
Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously stated, you should use a dot rather than a hash to access elements by class name.

As for the strikethrough, you should use the CSS text-decoration property:

```
$('.topBorderLight').css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
```

That said, it's much less brittle to add CSS classes to these elements and style those classes.

You could add some CSS like this:

```
.gradeOver5 {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Then, just add or remove the class based on the grade value:

```
$('.myElement').toggleClass('gradeOver5', grade > 5);
```

`toggleClass` adds or removes a class on an element based on a boolean value. Docs here: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

*Update*

So your complete JS might look like this:

```
$('.topBorderLight').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var grade = Number($this.text());
    if(!isNaN(grade)) {
        $this.toggleClass('gradeOver5', grade > 5);
    }
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dgrundel/btatr2wn/

Comment: Could you provide me a jsbin.com example with my html code please?

Comment: Added a JSFiddle to the answer!

Comment: but why its not making a line in the name Physics?

Comment: For that to happen, you'd need to apply the class to the row. Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/btatr2wn/1/

Answer (score 0):

The way to address a class in CSS and Javascript is by using a `.` (dot), addressing an id by using a `#` (hashtag).

As for your second request, you can use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.topBorderLight').each(function() {
        if($(this).text() > 5) {
             // do something   
        }
    });
});
```